# How to deploy to a server without build a projekt

Tags: deployment, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have an ImageVault website that we do not develop ourselves. But want version management in TFS and be able to publish against tests and production servers.
It does not need to be built because it is already finished.
How should you set up a building when you should not build anything?
Is it possible to set up a pipeline without having a building?

Comment: Hi @J.Klingwall Did you get a chance to try out below answer? Please let me know how did it go? We can discuss it to work out a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set up a pipeline that doesnot build your project. You project is built by the [build tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) in the pipeline. You can just disable or exclude the build tasks from your pipeline if you donot want your project be built.

You can also create an empty pipeline without any tasks inside. You can follow below steps to create an empty pipeline.

1,Sign in to your Azure DevOps organization and navigate to your project.

2,In your project, navigate to the Pipelines page. Choose the **Pipelines** tab and click new pipeline on the top right corner of the page.

3,Walk through the steps of the wizard by first selecting the location of your source code.(You can create a classic UI pipeline by choosing "**Use the classic editor to create a pipeline without YAML**".)

4,Then choose to start with An **Empty Job** under **Select a template**

With above steps, a pipeline without build tasks is created. You can then add some [utility tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) like **copy file task**, **publish artifacts task** etc. Utility tasks donot do the building work.

You might need to add some utility tasks like publish build artifacts tasks if you want to deploy release pipeline. 
[image]

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser%2Ctfs-2018-2) to learn more about creating your pipeline